# Why isn't my child selector #id > .test having an effect?

Tags: html, css

My html looks like this:

```
<div id="hi">
    <div class="test"></div>
<div>
```

and my css is as follows:

```
.test {
    background-color: red;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px; }

#id > .test {
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px solid black; }
```

Why isn't my test class div's background color getting changed to blue.

Here is an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hyb3Lbq4/) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: probably because #id means nothing. Try #hi.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hyb3Lbq4/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
#id > .test {
```

to

```
#hi > .test {
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant use `#id` you need to use `#hi` ....
try it